# Application Based Authorization through AWS Cognito and React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, amazon-cognito

I have integrated React Application with AWS cognito for authentication. Then i need to manage the User Group based application level authorization. Is it possible to keep the application based permission authorization on Cognito side:

for example: I'm going to login as MANAGER user group, then in React application I need to manage the UI visibility and functional approach based on the Cognito response when logging in as an authenticated user(MANAGER).

Is it possible or should I use a separate backend service to manage all user level permissions.

*If logging in as (MANAGER) shows different UI visibility + functionality;
Other users (CLIENT) shows different UI and functionality*

Please suggest me the best approach to develop using the React + AWS cognito Authentication + application level

I tried AWS Cognito integration and found that there are Role-based authorization only if we access another AWS services. But the thing is there is no need to access other service, what I need instead is to manage the User-based or UserGroup-based authorization in my React application after logging in as authenticated User.

I achieved what i need (application based Authorization) by creating a JAVA auth service application and there are REST apis to all authentication flow APIS and get Authorization based on the log in user

The database is PostgresSQL there are tables: user-group,groups,permissions,policies

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Amazon Cognito user pool to control who can access your API (if you are using Amazon API Gateway as well) you can refer here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

There is a blog post that describe more in detail about this as well https://dev.to/aws-builders/using-cognito-groups-to-control-access-to-api-endpoints-346g

Together with the access configuration about the endpoint based on user group - In your application code, you should be able to configure route to respective UI/page which your `MANAGER` or `CLIENT` should see / view.